# Can't pass the variable into other command

Tags: command-line, bash, environment-variables

I was trying to pass a variable another shell command.

To be clear;

```
passwdContent=$( getent passwd "$USER" )
echo "passwdcontent" $passwdContent
```

I get the "passwd" field from user "x".
After this section I want to play with this variable.

But in here I couldn't solve how can I pass the "passwdContent" variable.
I tried a way like this;

```
exampleVariable=[( "$passwdContent" | cut -d : -f 1 )]
```

After I want to echo the "exampleVariable" it gave me error.

I knew I can do this all of in one line. But I want to learn how can I do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use command substitution and for doing that you are missing a `$`.

You should also `pipe` the content of your variable to `cut` or read it from `stdin`.

So use this instead:

```
$ exampleVariable="[$(cut -d: -f1 <<<$passwdContent )]"
```

Now:

```
$ echo "$exampleVariable"
[ravexina]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to parse the output from getent.

```
$ [[ $(getent passwd "$USER") =~ ([^:]+):x: ]] && var=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```